# SerializableCoder cannot be cast to BeamRecordCoder

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I prepared  a `Pcollection<BeamRecord>` object from a file containing json objects using beam sql sdk.

The code below parse and map json lines to `ChatHistory` objects, then it converts the mapped objects to `BeamRecord`. Finally I try to use `BeamSql` on the returned `PCollection<BeamRecord>` but I get the exception SerializableCoder cannot be cast to BeamRecordCoder.

```
PCollection<ChatHistory> json_objects = lines.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractObjectsFn()));

    // Convert them to BeamRecords with the same schema as defined above via a DoFn.
      PCollection<BeamRecord> apps = json_objects.apply(
          ParDo.of(new DoFn<ChatHistory, BeamRecord>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                List<String> fields_list= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("conversation_id","message_type","message_date","message","message_auto_id"));
                List<Integer> types_list= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR));
                BeamRecordSqlType brtype = BeamRecordSqlType.create(fields_list, types_list);
                BeamRecord br = new BeamRecord(
                              brtype, 
                              c.element().conversation_id, 
                              c.element().message_type, 
                              c.element().message_date,
                              c.element().message, 
                              c.element().message_auto_id
                              );

                c.output(br);
            }
          })); 

      return apps.apply(
          BeamSql
              .query("SELECT conversation_id, message_type, message, message_date, message_auto_id FROM PCOLLECTION")
       );
```

Here is the generated stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder cannot be cast to org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.BeamRecordCoder
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.BeamSql$QueryTransform.registerTables (BeamSql.java:173)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.BeamSql$QueryTransform.expand (BeamSql.java:153)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.BeamSql$QueryTransform.expand (BeamSql.java:116)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal (Pipeline.java:537)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform (Pipeline.java:472)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionTuple.apply (PCollectionTuple.java:160)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.BeamSql$SimpleQueryTransform.expand (BeamSql.java:246)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.BeamSql$SimpleQueryTransform.expand (BeamSql.java:186)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal (Pipeline.java:537)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform (Pipeline.java:472)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply (PCollection.java:286)
at com.mdm.trial.trial3$JsonParse.expand (trial3.java:123)
at com.mdm.trial.trial3$JsonParse.expand (trial3.java:1)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal (Pipeline.java:537)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform (Pipeline.java:472)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply (PCollection.java:286)
at com.mdm.trial.trial3.main (trial3.java:160)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

I saw a similar post, but It still can't fix my error: [Running BeamSql WithoutCoder or Making Coder Dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806368/running-beamsql-withoutcoder-or-making-coder-dynamic?newreg=36e2fd62b72b4970bb019aabe7cbd798)

Best regards !

Comment: Is `SerializableCoder` a subclass of `BeamRecordCoder`?

Comment: No, SerializableCoder and BeamRecordCoder both extend CustomCoder

Comment: Welp, that'd be why.

Comment: But I don't know how to fix it, there is a function `.setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(BeamRecord.class))` but it didn't work. The guy in the post i've mentionned made it work somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ismail, in your case using the `.setCoder()` should work.

I would try extracting the row type out of the `ParDo`, and then applying it to `apps` before applying the SQL query:

```
  PCollection<ChatHistory> json_objects = lines.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractObjectsFn()));
  
  // Create a row type first:
  List<String> fields_list= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("conversation_id","message_type","message_date","message","message_auto_id"));
  List<Integer> types_list= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR));
  final BeamRecordSqlType brtype = BeamRecordSqlType.create(fields_list, types_list);
  
  // Convert them to BeamRecords with the same schema as defined above via a DoFn.
  PCollection<BeamRecord> apps = json_objects.apply(
      ParDo.of(new DoFn<ChatHistory, BeamRecord>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            BeamRecord br = new BeamRecord(
                          brtype, 
                          c.element().conversation_id, 
                          c.element().message_type, 
                          c.element().message_date,
                          c.element().message, 
                          c.element().message_auto_id
                          );
            c.output(br);
        }
      })); 
  
  return apps
    .setCoder(brtype.getRecordCoder())
    .apply(
      BeamSql
          .query("SELECT conversation_id, message_type, message, message_date, message_auto_id FROM PCOLLECTION")
   );
```

Couple of examples:

- [This example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/example/BeamSqlExample.java#L65) sets the coder by using `Create.withCoder()` which does the same thing;
- [This example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/e668688690325127becfaef7486d02a6dae3e101/sdks/java/nexmark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/nexmark/queries/sql/SqlQuery1.java#L71) filters and converts from `Events` using the [ToRow.parDo()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a13c7d9177c34017955cbfbfc29a7f4a698047c1/sdks/java/nexmark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/nexmark/model/sql/ToRow.java#L58) and then also sets the coder which is specified [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/11ad97e42015dc497fb5cc3d38090e64f9c7418b/sdks/java/nexmark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/nexmark/model/sql/adapter/ModelAdaptersMapping.java#L72);

Please note that `BeamRecord` has been renamed to `Row`, and few other changes are reflected in the examples above.

Comment: I have tried to implement my requirement using the above code. Can you please specify ExtractObjectsFn() ?

Comment: I assume that's a custom parsing logic implemented by author. It looks like what happens before this code sample is:  
 1) `lines` is a `PCollection` of strings or something similar, each representing a json object. It is probably obtained from a `PubSub` topic, log files, some service, or any other source;
 2) `ExtractObjectsFn()` looks at those lines and creates `ChatHistory` objects from them. It's up to you how this kind of logic is implemented.
  Usually for something like this you would create a `ParDo` which  
 takes in a json string and outputs its java representation;